# When are MediaManager Distributions Live?

Tags: publishing, media-manager

With the MediaManager (MM) Connector in Tridion, via MM Mountpoint we can upload an asset which automatically creates a program and distribution in MM.

When are the distributions live--after the upload (via MM's Connector) or when we publish in Tridion (TBB)?

Also does unpublishing in Tridion take a MM distribution offline (I'd imagine not, since it might be used elsewhere)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is live when it is created in MM.

Publish/Unpublish has no effect on the distribution in Media Manager.

Comment: @alvin-reyes in Media Manager there is a **put live** and **take offline**, but that is not (yet) wired through via the MM Connector

Comment: Aye, I'm now wondering the best way to keep MM distributions offline or just hidden between Tridion and MM. New question, Bart?